# How can I access variables only declared in a template?

Tags: url, variable, function

I have a template inside a folder located in `/templates` that is not related to any entry or section:

**/folder/test.html**

```
{% extends '_layout' %}

{% set title            = 'myTitle' %}
{% set description      = 'myDescription' %}
{% set variable3        = 'hello' %}


{% block content %}

    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ description }}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

If I want to create a link to this page, I can use the `url()` function like this:

```
<a href="{{ url('folder/test') }}">test</a>
```

How can I access the variables declared on this page?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. I think the best way to access 'unattached' variables is to create a global field set and attach fields to it. That way you'll be able to access them anywhere.

`{{ globalSet1.title }}`
`{{ globalSet1.description }}`
`{{ globalSet1.variable3 }}`

Comment: As a side note, in the case of extending a template, the master template (i.e. "_layout") can access variables declared in the child-template directly — if you are trying for example, to define your 'title', 'description', etc. for the your "_layout" master.